Combustion-less engine for planes?
This is surely dumb for a simple reason, but why wouldn't a simple convergent-divergent nozzle placed on a plane going near mach 1 generate thrust? Would it not compress the fluid to mach 1 and then upon expansion eject it at supersonic speeds, much higher than it entered? Something's off with energy conservation but I can't seem to find what.

Show your working then people may point out the error to you.

Jet engines use combustion to create the energy for making the plane go.  Without combustion you have what, a vinegar & baking soda rocket?  Maybe a pump up rocket?

Compressing the air takes work. That will induce drag.
"You can't win. You can't even break even!" (I don't know who said it first.)

And which of the Laws of Thermodynamics is that? :)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginsberg%27s_theorem

@TigerGuy, Thanks for the link!

@SolarMike, it's the law of the bicycle pump.

I know it does not play well with energy conservation, but I'm wondering why it does not generate thrust, intuitively, since air enters at a certain speed and is ejected at a higher one. Compressing the air might take work but the expansion generates thrust no?

Compressing the air will take more work than will be released during expansion. You always lose.

Ok, by conservation of momentum something needs to gain speed in the opposite direction. Is it particles hitting the outside of the nozzle that involves drag? Or something else?

Intuitively it does not generate a net thrust because that would violate energy conservation and (A) Emily Noerther rules, and (B) the universe isn't expanding that fast.  It may be that if you sliced the thing right in half lengthwise that one half or another would generate thrust -- but only if the other half was generating even more drag.

Popeye,  if the engine airflow gets sped up to mach 1, the shock wave inside the engine will choke the airflow  and it will not exit the engine faster than it entered it.  Furthermore, no combustion equals no thrust- only drag.
If you could harvest thrust from a convergent/divergent nozzle, you'd have a perpetual motion machine and no one would be using jet engines.
